# Replacing text string in dataframe with a probability sampled alternative

Tags: r, performance, apply

I'm using R, and I have a large dataframe where the number of rows is in the millions.
I am specifically interested though in just one column, $path.
From within this data I have generated an index which identifies entries I wish to replace:

```
replace.index <- which(df$path == 'First')
```

and imagine this index identifies 50 rows.

In a separate table, I have identified a probability table which I wish to use to 'sample' from in order to replace each of these 'First' entries.

Imagine this second entity is a series of named numbers called "casetable":

```
      cum
alpha 18
beta  29
gamma 40
delta 50
```

where this 50 matches the number of rows I wish to replace.

I am trying to write some kind of replace action which substitutes

```
18 cases of "First" with "alpha > First"
11 cases of "First" with "beta > First"
11 cases of "First" with "gamma > First"
10 cases of "First" with "delta > First"
```

and in essence overwrites the entry in each of the previously identified rows in the main table.

I'm confident I can run this with a for loop, but for speed I'd like to use an apply function instead, which I'm not able to work out. I've tried the following but I can't get it right:

```
#'Replacement function'
sampleprevious <- function(rndtbl,upperlimit,reattach) {
  return(paste0(names(rndtbl[max(which(rndtbl < runif(1, min=1, max=upperlimit)))])
  ,' > ', reattach))
}

df$path[replace.index] <-
    mapply(paste0, sampleprevious(casetable, 50, 'First'))
```

This is a compromise attempt using a random number sampling as I wasn't sure how else to get my repeats, but what I get for this is just a singly sampled value populated against each row rather than 50 separate samplings.

I'd be happy with help to generate 50 random samplings, but equally happy with just the derived splits 18|11|11|10 please.

*_____________
** Addenda **
I have solved the 'sampling' version using this:

```
sampleprevious <- function(rndtbl,upperlimit,reattach) {
  return(paste0(names(rndtbl[min(which(rndtbl > runif(1, min=1, max=upperlimit-1)))])
  ,'>', reattach))
}

df$path[replace.index] <-
  replicate(50, sampleprevious(casetable, 50, 'First'))
```

and this will give me a random proportion in line with my casetable. I'd still in a way prefer to generate exactly the number of rows from my casetable.

Comment: The relationship between `casetable` and the desired outcome isn't clear to me. Can you elaborate? It it supposed to give sampling weights?

Comment: Yes, it is. I have pre-calculated how many of each 'First' entries I want to replace with each new string. The First entries are scattered across my dataframe, I'm just trying to find them, and with a probability of n/50 replace them with a new string. In my casetable I have used a cumulative total in order to allow a simple probability function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reproducible data where the `tension` variable is your `path`:

```
data(warpbreaks)
warpbreaks$tension <- as.character(warpbreaks$tension)
```

`casetable` will give the replacement values and their weights.

```
casetable <- data.frame(replacement = letters[1:3], n = c(2, 4, 6),
                        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#   replacement n
# 1           a 2
# 2           b 4
# 3           c 6
```

We need to know how many replacements to sample.

```
subset_n <- sum(warpbreaks$tension == "L")
# [1] 18
```

sample `subset_n` values from the `replacement` column of `casetable`, with probabilities from its `n` column, and replace the existing values of the `tension` column in `warpbreaks` where `tension` is a particular value, `L`. (This is `First` in your data.)

```
warpbreaks[warpbreaks$tension == "L", "tension"] <- 
  sample(casetable$replacement, size = subset_n, replace = TRUE,
         prob = casetable$n)
warpbreaks
#    breaks wool tension
# 1      26    A       c
# 2      30    A       b
# 3      54    A       c
# 4      25    A       c
# 5      70    A       c
# 6      52    A       a
# 7      51    A       b
# 8      26    A       b
# 9      67    A       c
# 10     18    A       M
# 11     21    A       M
# 12     29    A       M
```

Comment: Yes - I can follow that, thank you. I think I'd decided I needed some kind of list function, but really I can just swap the data in from a list by assigning it. Many thanks, question answered.